# How to sort nested items?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a plain list of persons `List<Person>`

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public List<Person> Childs { get; set; }
}
```

so I want to sort it to have a list of persons without a `ParentId` and all children of a person are added to his `Childs`. I've no idea how to do it, any tips?

Comment: Do you want to sort by `Id`?

Comment: @GrantWinney yes, `0` or null

Comment: @Selman22 no, I want a list of grandpas! their children are assigned in `Childs` property

Comment: but that is not sorting ?? also do you have a `Grandpa` class or you just want to create new persons with childrens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking for, but seems like you're trying to get tree-like structure form single-dimmentional list of `Person`.

```
var dict = source.ToDictionary(x => x.Id);

foreach(var p in source)
    if(p.ParentId != 0)
        dict[p.ParentId].Childs.Add(p);

var topLevel = source.Where(p => p.ParentId == 0).ToList();
```

I assumed `ParentId == 0` means there is no parent, and that item is top level item.

Comment: I think last statement is `dict.Where(..`

Comment: @user3293835 It doesn't matter, because they both contain the same items, just in different form.

Comment: I thought `.ToDictionary()` gives a new instance and changing one won't change the other. new lesson. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should work a treat:

```
var lookup = people.ToLookup(p => p.ParentId);

foreach (var person in people)
{
    person.Childs = lookup[person.Id].ToList();
}
```

If the `Childs` collection is already instantiated then use this:

```
    person.Childs.AddRange(lookup[person.Id]);
```